# Receiving the push even when push is disabled with SFMC SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, react-native, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

In my react-native mobile application I've integrated push notification via this library. https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk . However, I used `.disablePush()` to disable the push notification. And to make sure I logged the state with `.isPushEnabled()` as well. But I still receive the push notification even the status shows that I've disabled the push.

What might be the case ? Do I need some other way to do that ? I'm looking to build in-app push enable toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Post setting disablePush(), the updated value should be registered to the backend (Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile Push Platform). The backend then will not send any push notifications to the corresponding device once opted-out. Please ensure that the opt-out status is updated to the backend.

Thanks,
Prakashini

Comment: What do you mean by Backend ? Do you mean the Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile Push Platform ?

Comment: Yes, thats right! Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile Push platform.